# Xcode scrollView that changes its y position using Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, xcode7

Here's my setup: I have a `ViewController` that contains an image(button). This button takes the user to another `viewController` using an `@IBAction func` (tab controller tab). However, I also want a `scrollView` on the initial `ViewController`, just under the image button.

What I'm trying to achieve is the ability to scroll content on top of the image button as if it were another page on top of the image button. As the user scroll back down, the image button is revealed underneath the `scrollView` and is clickable again.

I can't seem to find a solution anywhere online. My scrollView is either fixed below the image button, or covers the image button rendering it unclickable.

**Here's a screenshot**

[image: Here's a screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at the demo project i set up:
https://github.com/slotti85/ButtonAndScrollView

i...

- put the scrollview all over the screen (also over the button),
- set up a `contentInset` to make the button visible initially,
- subclassed `UIScrollView` and
- overrode the `pointInside` function to make the scrollview forward a touch if the "transparent area" is tapped.

hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Your example works exactly as I need, however I guess the setup of my scrollview and the subview constraints are not aligned with what you have in your example project. I keep getting this error: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Would you like to share your Project so I can take a look?

Comment: maybe upload it to github? or dropbox?

Comment: ahm... looks kind of empty to me :P

Comment: Project should be there

Comment: yes, there is a project... but without any code or something (except of the default storyboard and viewcontroller)...

Comment: Updated github, sorry. Looks like the files are there now.

Comment: now it looks better. which is the viewcontroller you have the problems with?

Comment: FourthViewController.swift. The button doesn't work now.

Comment: I guess I missed that small detail. Thanks for you help! It's working now! I really appreciate it. Saved me more hours of trial and error!!

Comment: glad i could help :)